# Color interpolation across a polygon mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

What is the best way to interpolate colors across a polygon mesh where all of the polygons have the same normal and considerable color differences? Is Using GLSL (with gouraud or phong shading) the right approach or should I take this elsewhere (on cpu side)? Or do I get this completely wrong?

ps: I'm using OpenGL 4.0+

I would like to interpolate colors on a mesh like this.

[image: Colored polygon mesh]

Comment: I've never done this but I would compute the mean color of each vertex by using colors of adjacent triangles, and then interpolate colors for each facets. Dunno if it's what you are looking for...

Comment: Those vertices don't have colors. The *faces* have colors, but not the vertices.

Comment: My point was assigning color to vertices in order to interpolate color on each facets.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your picture you need to do a flat shading per triangle(face).
In you vertex buffer you can add vertex color attribute per triangle.In fact it is going to be a color per vertex so if you are using an [interleaved vertex buffer array](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices) it may look as follows :

```
[
 vertex1.x , vertex1.y , vertex1.z ,vertex1color.r ,vertex1color.g ,vertex1color.b,
 vertex2.x , vertex2.y , vertex2.z ,vertex2color.r ,vertex2color.g ,vertex2color.b,
 vertex3.x , vertex3.y , vertex3.z ,vertex32color.r vertex3color.g ,vertex3color.b

..... the same for the rest of triangles ...
]
```

Then, in the vertex shader you set a varying for output color which is then used by the fragment shader to "paint" your fragments.Now, **it's important you set no interpolation for that varying but flat**.So that the colors aren't interpolated across the primitive.
[Here](http://poniesandlight.co.uk/notes/flat_shading_on_osx/) is an example of how to do it.(If you are using GLSL 330 or later then substitute "varying" with in / out )